Java template engine with spring boot application not running in Intellj
I am using the Spring authorization server with custom branding and a custom login page, with the below dependency and configuration and java template engine.
plugins {
    java
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "3.3.5"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.1.6"
    id("gg.jte.gradle") version "3.1.12"
}

group = "school.staff"
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"

java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(21)
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-authorization-server")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation("gg.jte:jte:3.1.12")
    implementation("gg.jte:jte-spring-boot-starter-3:3.1.12")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher")
}

jte {
    generate()
    binaryStaticContent = true
}

tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

Below project layout

Running in Intellij IDE with this configuration

Logs when running using Intellij IDE
org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access Denied
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:98) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.4.jar:6.3.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.4.jar:6.3.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.4.jar:6.3.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:120) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.4.jar:6.3.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.4.jar:6.3.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:100) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.4.jar:6.3.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.4.jar:6.3.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:179) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.4.jar:6.3.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.4.jar:6.3.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.4.jar:6.3.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.4.jar:6.3.4]

However the code and project works perfectly fine with ./gradlew bootrun or from any other IDE like VScode or Fleet
This is the issue from the IDE, not sure what is happening.
